# How to protect some REST requests using a second factor of authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have Resource Service (REST service) and some other services which use Resource Service.

Resource Service protected via OAuth. In addition, it is necessary that some requests were protected by OTP (one type password), which comes via SMS.

I know how to generate code and sends it via SMS, but I don't know how to organize Rest controller and what to do after receiving request to resource.

For example: we do GET request to Controller /api/user. At this moment Resource server sends message to user's phone and what next ?

- I can't do another endpoint to get otp and then send it with HTTP Header or Request body, because It's necessary that other services didn't know this code.

How to correct organise this interaction?
How to organize such protection of Rest Service?

We use Spring. 
Thanks a lot for any advices.

Comment: The big question is how the user input the code from the SMS

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can do this trick:

1. Create REST service with dynamic path. `/rest/some/service/unique-long-id`
2. Do not request security to this dynamic path.
3. Create service to chek if `unique-long-id` exists, not expired and give access to Resource Service.
4. Once user POSTs SMS code, redirect to this dynamic path only for this user.

Example:

You send SMS pin-code: `1234567890`

REST service validates this pin-code and redirects me to

`/rest/some/service/c83b5cf29d264ac7b86f27cc77af3f54979feefaf820edae36b2518a7e613385`

If this unique-code is valid, you give me access to Resource Service. If not, 404 error or 401 error.

**EDIT:**

Two ways to achieve your requirements:

- `ServiceB` needs to validate dynamic ID to grant access for `/api/protectedResource/unique-long-id`.
- Use [filters](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm) to intercept URL (`/api/protectedResource/unique-long-id`) for `ServiceB`. If it passes validation, grant or deny access for protected resources.

In first case, `ServiceA` generates a code and notifies user. `ServiceB` gives access only if valid pin-code is sent with dynamic URL:

Look this simulation:

```js
var secretCode;

function generateCode(){
    secretCode = parseInt(Math.random() * 100000000);
    wrongCode  = (secretCode+"").split("").reverse().join("");
    $("#serviceA").val(secretCode);
    $("#resource1").val("/api/protectedResource/" +  wrongCode);
    $("#resource1").attr("onclick", "getAccess('" + wrongCode + "', 'protectedResource1')");
  
    $("#resource2").val("/api/protectedResource/" + secretCode);
    $("#resource2").attr("onclick", "getAccess('" + secretCode + "', 'protectedResource2')");
  
    $("#protectedResource1").val("");
    $("#protectedResource2").val("");
  
}

function getAccess(code, id){
    $("#" + id).val($("#serviceA").val() === code ? "Access granted" : "Access denied");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

ServiceA<br>
POST <input type="button" value="/api/user" onclick="generateCode()" /> Secret code: <input id="serviceA" type="text" value="" />

<br>
<br>
ServiceB<br>
Wrong-ID POST <input id="resource1" type="button" value="/api/protectedResource/-1" onclick="getAccess('-1', 'protectedResource1')" /> Response <input id="protectedResource1" type="text" readonly="true" value="" />
<br>
Correct-ID POST <input id="resource2" type="button" value="/api/protectedResource/-1" onclick="getAccess('1234567890', 'protectedResource2')" /> Response <input id="protectedResource2" type="text" readonly="true" value="" />
```

If you need help, we can open chat

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't quite understand the algorithm. Could you explain more detail please. My Rest service = ServiceA. ServiceB try to get some protected resource. For example, /api/protectedResource/